# Lyapunov equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, control-theory, linear-control

This question is from a system theory test without answers or solutions:

Let the following two cases be given

$A) \quad A=\begin{bmatrix}-2&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix} \quad $and$ \quad C=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1 \end{bmatrix} \qquad B) \quad A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&1 \end{bmatrix} \quad $and$ \quad C=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}$

and consider the following two statements

$\quad \textbf{1.}$ There exists a solution $W \succ 0$ to

$\quad \qquad WA+A^TW-C^TC \prec 0$

$\quad \textbf{2.}$ There exists a solution $P \succ 0$ to

$\quad \qquad PA+A^TP+C^TC=0$

$\qquad $that is given by the integral expression

$\quad \qquad P:=\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{At})^TC^TCe^{At}dt$

Which of the statements

My approach:

First for case $A)$ we check statement $1$

$\begin{bmatrix}W_1&W_2\\W_2&W_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-2&1\\-1&0 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}-2&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}W_1&W_2\\W_2&W_3\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}=0$

We multiply the matrices and bring $\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}$ to the other side of the $=$ sign. Which gives:

$\begin{bmatrix}-4W_1-2W_2&W_1-2W_2-W_3\\W_1-2W_2-W_3&2W_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}$

In order to solve this we construct the matrix:

$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}-4&-2&0&1\\1&-2&-1&-1\\0&2&0&1\end{array}\right] 
 \rightarrow \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}1&0&0&-\frac{1}{2}\\0&1&0&\frac{1}{2}\\0&0&1&-\frac{1}{2}\end{array} \right]\quad$and thus $\quad W=\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$

Which is not positive definite (the eigenvalues are $0$ and $-1$), so for $A$ statement 1 is false.

The existence of a positive definite $P$ can be checked in  a similar way.
So the rest is just a repetition of the steps taken above.

Is this the correct way to solve these questions?

Comment: which text book did you use? did you study the properties of Lyapunov equations? There are well known conditions on A under which existence an uniqueness of solutions P are established. Using these lemmas one only need to check some properties of A.

Comment: I used the book Linear Systems Theory by Joao Hespanha.

Comment: I included an answer below relying on a theorem from the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 12.5 from the book Linear Systems Theory by Joao Hespanha (page 115) may be used. Here, you need for example to check the controllability of $(A,C)$, see points 5 and 6 in the theorem in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: So all I have to do is determine the eigenvalues of $A$ and if those are $< 0$ then there exist both a $W \succ 0$ for $WA+A^TW-C^TC \prec 0$ and a $P \succ 0$ for $PA+A^TP+C^TC = 0$